# Adding wifi type monitor - adds as managed

Tags: wireless-networking, display

I've just received my Alfa AWUS036H and is eager to try it out.
I'm running kali 2.0 latest release, on an old Dell Latitude D630. 
The wifi adapter was plug-and-play, diver-wise.

I wanted to try to sniff out SSID's, and tried to add a monitor interface with the following command:

```
~# sudo iw phy phy1 interface add mon0 type monitor
~# sudo iw dev
```

But its saved as managed

```
phy#1
         Interface mon0
         wdev ...
         addr ...
         type managed
```

the stock wifi card is still in play, at phy0 as wlan0.

Why is it stored as managed when i specify monitor?

**Edit 1**

I've also tested `airmon-ng start wlan1` and it creates a new interface called wlan1mon, but that one is also managed.

Comment: I usually use *aircrack-ng* to do wireless stuff. You have kali, which comes with *aircrack-ng* try this command. `airmon-ng start wlan0` Change wlan0 to your device name. And `airodump-ng mon0` to view the SSIDs.

Comment: I've tried that aswell! It sais "monitor mode vif enabled for [phy2]wlan1 on [phy2]wlan1mon" but wlan1mon is also type managed.. Its wired. Could it be a faulty alfa adapter?